# tikz graphs library: Edge label syntax

Tags: tikz-graphs

I'm using tikz and its "graph" library, and I'd like to label some of my graph's edges. The tikz manual (pgfmanual.pdf v3.0.1, p. 364) suggests the syntax

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}
\tikz \graph
{
  a ->["foo"] b
};
\end{document}
```

However, this doesn't work; upon compilation I get the error message

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/"{foo}"' and I am going t
 o ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in tikz or its documentation?

By the way, the alternative syntax `->[edge label=foo]` works fine.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX ! I get the same message errors as you do, and the `[edge label=foo]` also works for me. The same things go for the examples in the manual using the `["foo"]` syntax. I think this is either a bug or a case of the manual not being up to date. Please post a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), so other users can test more easily.

Comment: Did you load the `quotes` library?

Comment: @cfr That's it for me : `\usetikzlibrary{quotes}` ! Well spotted ! Is this requirement documented in the manual close enough to the graph examples ?

Comment: @cfr: Thanks, that does the trick. Care to submit this as an answer?

Comment: @marsupilam It is a standard feature of the Ti*k*Z manual not to mention the need for libraries which are incidental to the topic currently being covered. That is, probably not, but that's a problem running throughout the manual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the `quotes` library.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,quotes}
\begin{document}
\tikz \graph
{
  a ->["foo"] b
};
\end{document}
```

[image: graph with label]